# ghostscript: numbering pages via command line

Tags: ghostscript

a question (maybe silly, maybe not)

In windows, used a grafical frontend to ghostscript

*free pdf fill tools*
- www.freepdffill.com

one tools of this frontend, makes you able to *stamp* numbers on pages of

a pdf, choosing size, position, font... and so on...

Now I switched to linux, I have ghostscript, so, I think, I'm able to do 
the same thing from command-line, but I can't find or understand how 
command line options to numbering pages

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe pspdftool is what you want.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pspdftool/ I know it from this page.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603301/how-to-add-page-numbers-to-postscript-pdf

Answer (score -1):

When I convert using ghostscript I use:

-sOutputFile=exprtedfilename-%d.jpg

and the -%d gets replaced with the page number.