# How to add page numbers to Postscript/PDF

Tags: pdf, postscript

If you've got a large document (500 pages+) in Postscript and want to add page numbers, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Override the `showpage` operator as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620599/477035) to an essentially [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4766755/477035)

Comment: See [Alan Munn's very nice solution on TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18762/3406).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might be a solution:

1. convert postscript to pdf using `ps2pdf`
2. create a LaTeX file and insert the pages using the *pdfpages* package (`\includepdf`)
3. use `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` or something from the *fancyhdr* package in the arguments of `\includepdf`
4. if postscript output is required, convert the pdflatex output back to postscript via `pdf2ps`

Comment: I think this is a great idea, but it I haven't got it working. The page numbers don't insert *over* the \includepdf pages.

Comment: Have you used something like `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{document.pdf}`?

Comment: This is essentially what Alan Munn does in [his solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18762/3406), minus the PS stuff.

Answer (score 27):

Based on rcs's proposed solution, I did the following:

Converted the document to `example.pdf` and ran `pdflatex addpages`, where `addpages.tex` reads:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\topmargin 70pt
\oddsidemargin 70pt

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\Large\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true,scale=0.98,pages=-]{example.pdf}
% fitpaper & scale aren't always necessary - depends on the paper being submitted.
\end{document}
```

or alternatively, for two-sided pages (i.e. with the page number consistently on the outside):

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\topmargin 70pt
\oddsidemargin 150pt
\evensidemargin -40pt

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\Large\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includepdfset{pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\includepdf{target.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Easy way to change header margins:

```
% set margins for headers, won't shrink included pdfs
% you can remove the topmargin/oddsidemargin/evensidemargin lines
\usepackage[margin=1in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
```

Comment: It looks good. It seems that it removes internal bookmarks from `example.pdf`,  though.

Answer (score 20):

you can simply use

**pspdftool**

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pspdftool

in this way:

```
pspdftool 'number(x=-1pt,y=-1pt,start=1,size=10)' input.pdf output.pdf
```

see these two examples (unnumbered and **numbered** pdf with pspdftool)

**unnumbered pdf**

http://ge.tt/7ctUFfj2

**numbered pdf**

http://ge.tt/7ctUFfj2

with this as the first command-line argument:

```
number(start=1, size=40, x=297.5 pt, y=10 pt)
```

Comment: Speaking of broken links, those example .pdf hyperlinks are broken.

Comment: sorry, I'll strive to replace as soon as possible

Comment: As of april/2017, _ifile.it_ links are dead.

Comment: sorry for dead links, I'll strive to replace as soon as possible

Comment: links updated and working now; thanks for alerting me ;-)

Comment: Is `pspdftool` available on macOS?

Comment: @HappyFace It’s said to be compatible with BSD systems and is a simple C project with very few dependencies, so you should have no problem compiling in on macOS. See the INSTALL file. Maybe you’ll have to install a few packages with e.g. [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), such as zlib, gmake or autotools.

Answer (score 18):

I used to add page numbers to my pdf using latex like in the accepted answer.

Now I found an easier way:
Use `enscript` to create empty pages with a header containing the page number, and then use `pdftk` with the `multistamp` option to put the header on your file.

This bash script expects the pdf file as it's only parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
output="${1%.pdf}-header.pdf"
pagenum=$(pdftk "$input" dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2)
enscript -L1 --header='||Page $% of $=' --output - < <(for i in $(seq "$pagenum"); do echo; done) | ps2pdf - | pdftk "$input" multistamp - output $output
```

Comment: warning for other users: only since build 1.43 pdftk has *multistamp* feature - regarding to code I can suggest  output="${1%03d.pdf}-header.pdf" to have zero equalization

Comment: Multistamp is great. Enscript however is not very flexible for this use case - I tried to get the line numbers centered in the footer, with the font I want etc... What I ended up doing is creating 1000 pages with my word processor, with auto line numbers in the footer. Then I just multistamp it on my files.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Bucle does not iterate, I've tried hardcoding $pagenum value, but nothing.

Comment: For me dump_data give a line for each page and seq gives an error. With an additional "tail -n1" it worked for me: pagenum=$(pdftk "$input" dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2 | tail -n1)

Comment: Could you please explain this a bit for beginners like me.

Comment: `brew install pdftk-java` for macOS.

Comment: How do we move the position of the headers?

Answer (score 17):

I was looking for a postscript-only solution, using ghostscript. I needed this to merge multiple PDFs and put a counter on every page. Only solution I found was [an old gs-devel posting](https://www.ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2005-May/006956.html), which I heavily simplified:

```
%!PS
% add page numbers document bottom right (20 units spacing , harcoded below)
% Note: Page dimensions are expressed in units of the default user space (72nds of an inch).
% inspired by https://www.ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2005-May/006956.html

globaldict /MyPageCount 1 put % initialize page counter

% executed at the end of each page. Before calling the procedure, the interpreter
% pushes two integers on the operand stack:
% 1. a count of previous showpage executions for this device
% 2. a reason code indicating the circumstances under which this call is being made:
%    0: During showpage or (LanguageLevel 3) copypage
%    1: During copypage (LanguageLevel 2 only)
%    2: At device deactivation
% The procedure must return a boolean value specifying whether to transmit the page image to the
% physical output device.
<< /EndPage {
  exch pop % remove showpage counter (unused)
  0 eq dup { % only run and return true for showpage
    /Helvetica 12 selectfont % select font and size for following operations
    MyPageCount =string cvs % get page counter as string
    dup % need it twice (width determination and actual show)
    stringwidth pop % get width of page counter string ...
    currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get % get width from PageSize on stack
    exch sub 20 sub % pagewidth - stringwidth - some extra space
    20 moveto % move to calculated x and y=20 (0/0 is the bottom left corner)
    show % finally show the page counter
    globaldict /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put % increment page counter
  } if
} bind >> setpagedevice
```

If you save this to a file called `pagecount.ps` you can use it on command line like this:

```
gs \
  -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
  -sOutputFile=/path/to/merged.pdf \
  -f pagecount.ps -f input1.pdf -f input2.pdf
```

Note that pagecount.ps must be given first (technically, right before the the input file which the page counting should start with).

If you don't want to use an extra `.ps` file, you can also use a minimized form like this:

```
gs \
  -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
  -sOutputFile=/path/to/merged.pdf \
  -c 'globaldict /MyPageCount 1 put << /EndPage {exch pop 0 eq dup {/Helvetica 12 selectfont MyPageCount =string cvs dup stringwidth pop currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get exch sub 20 sub 20 moveto show globaldict /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put } if } bind >> setpagedevice' \
  -f input1.pdf -f input2.pdf
```

Depending on your input, you may have to use `gsave`/`grestore` at the beginning/end of the if block.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I hacked on it for a bit, thinking that it would be possible to get rid of /MyPageCount and simply use the page number the interpreter puts on the stack, but that doesn't work for at least some PDFs; with those, the "device deactivation" seems to be called after *each page*, and *then* showpage is called with a never-incrementing page count.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx yes, I also wondered why the "count of previous showpage executions for this device" always stayed at `1` (IIRC), but never came around the reason and it did not matter enough for further investigation. There are [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30426517/6735159) that seem to use it successfully.

Comment: If in addition you wish to display the total page number: `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -o "$output" -c "globaldict /MyPageCount 1 put /concatstrings { exch dup length 2 index length add string dup dup 4 2 roll copy length 4 -1 roll putinterval } bind def << /EndPage {exch pop 0 eq dup {/Helvetica 12 selectfont MyPageCount =string cvs ( / $npages) concatstrings dup stringwidth pop currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get exch sub 20 sub 20 moveto show globaldict /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put } if } bind >> setpagedevice" -f input1.pdf`

Comment: ... where `npages` is defined as: `npages="$(qpdf --show-npages input1.pdf)"`

Comment: Nice. It works fine, and the resulting pdf still has internal links. I think that the last command requires a `\` before the last line.

Comment: @EricDuminil I guess you mean that there's backslash \ missing, right? Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: @Jakob: Exactly. I forgot to escape the escape character. :D Thanks.

Comment: If the stuff of your PDF is motley and bare page numbers look 'interflowing' into background, you can try this solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2GwO.gif https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937645/

Comment: The script without using the .ps file was very useful to dynamically set the page start number. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I liked the idea of using [pspdftool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pspdftool/) ([man page](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/21931990/numer/1/nazwa/pspdftool)) but what I was after was **page x out of y** format and the font style to match the rest of the page.

To find out about the font names used in the document:

```
$ strings input.pdf | grep Font
```

To get the number of pages:

```
$ pdfinfo input.pdf | grep "Pages:" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f2
```

Glue it together with a few `pspdftool` commands:

```
$ in=input.pdf; \
out=output.pdf; \
indent=30; \
pageNumberIndent=49; \
pageCountIndent=56; \
font=LiberationSerif-Italic; \
fontSize=9; \
bottomMargin=40; \
pageCount=`pdfinfo $in | grep "Pages:" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f2`; \
pspdftool "number(x=$pageNumberIndent pt, y=$bottomMargin pt, start=1, size=$fontSize, font=\"$font\")" $in tmp.pdf; \
pspdftool "text(x=$indent pt, y=$bottomMargin pt, size=$fontSize, font=\"$font\", text=\"page \")" tmp.pdf tmp.pdf; \
pspdftool "text(x=$pageCountIndent pt, y=$bottomMargin pt, size=$fontSize, font=\"$font\", text=\"out of $pageCount\")" tmp.pdf $out; \
rm tmp.pdf;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: pspdftools allows you to pass in a string to format the page number, so you can do this in one shot:
`pspdftool "number(x=$pageNumberIndent pt, y=$bottomMargin pt, start=1, size=$fontSize, font=\"$font\", text=\"page %d out of $pageCount\")" $in $out`

Answer (score 5):

Further to captaincomic's solution, I've extended it to support the starting of page numbering at any page.

Requires enscript, pdftk 1.43 or greater and pdfjam (for pdfjoin utility)

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
count=$2
blank=$((count - 1))
output="${1%.pdf}-header.pdf"
pagenum=$(pdftk "$input" dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2)
(for i in $(seq "$blank"); do echo; done) | enscript -L1 -B --output - | ps2pdf - > /tmp/pa$$.pdf
(for i in $(seq "$pagenum"); do echo; done) | enscript -a ${count}- -L1 -F Helvetica@10 --header='||Page $% of $=' --output - | ps2pdf - > /tmp/pb$$.pdf
pdfjoin --paper letter --outfile /tmp/join$$.pdf /tmp/pa$$.pdf /tmp/pb$$.pdf &>/dev/null
cat /tmp/join$$.pdf | pdftk "$input" multistamp - output "$output"
rm /tmp/pa$$.pdf
rm /tmp/pb$$.pdf
rm /tmp/join$$.pdf
```

For example.. place this in /usr/local/bin/pagestamp.sh and execute like:

```
pagestamp.sh doc.pdf 3
```

This will start the page number at page 3.. useful when you have coversheets, title pages and table of contents, etc.

The unfortunate thing is that enscript's --footer option is broken, so you cannot get the page numbering at the bottom using this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the free and open source [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) to add page numbers to a PDF file with a single command line.

The command line you could use is (on GNU/Linux you have to escape the `$` sign in the shell, on Windows it is not necessary):

`pdftools.py --input-file ./input/wikipedia_algorithm.pdf --output ./output/addtext.pdf --text "\$page/\$pages" br 1 1 --overwrite`

Regarding the `--text` option:

- The first parameter is the text to add. Some placeholders are available. `$page` stands for the current page number, while `$pages` stands for the total number of pages in the PDF file. Thus the option so formulated would add something like "1/10" for the first page of a 10-page PDF document, and so on for the following pages
- The second parameter is the anchor point of the text box. "br" will position the bottom right corner of the text box
- The third parameter is the horizontal position of the anchor point of the text box as a percentage of the page width. Must be a number between `0` and `1`, with the dot `.` separating decimals
- The fourth parameter option is the vertical position of the anchor point on the text box as a percentage of the page height. Must be a number between `0` and `1`, with the dot `.` separating decimals

Disclaimer: I'm the author of pdftools

Comment: thank you! I tried this but it only shows / without putting the page numbers... it is like the $page $pages variables dont populate...

Comment: @AAA If you are on GNU/Linux, you have to escape the `$` sign from the shell, so you have to write `\$` and not just `$`: call it `pdftools.py [...] --text \$page/\$pages [...]`

Comment: with single quotes, shell doesn't interpolate. `'$page / $pages'`

Comment: But how to move the `br` so it's not **right down against the corner**? I've tried `br 5 5`, `br -10 -10` -- it goes off page or doesn't show up

Comment: @usretc what is the end result you are trying to achieve? You can also open an issue on the GitHub page of pdftools. `br 0.9 0.9` will put the bottom right corner of the text box you are adding 90% from the left margin of the page and 90% from the top margin of the page

Comment: The two numbers after `br` are between 0 and 1

Comment: that was exactly it, somehow I got stuck thinking about absolute units

Comment: Also for some reason the `temp` directory is not removed automatically after a successful run.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov can you open an issue on [github](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools/issues) and type the exact command line you used? I tested it again on my system and I cannot find the temp directory after a successful run

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was running with `--debug` flag. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov yeah that would explain it

Answer (score 3):

Oh, it's a long time since I used postscript, but a quick dip into the blue book will tell you :) www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/BLUEBOOK.PDF

On the other hand, Adobe Acrobat and a bit of javascript would also do wonders ;)

Alternatively, I did find this: http://www.ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2005-May/006956.html, which seems to fit the bill (I didn't try it)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for a PS-based solution. There is no page-level operator in PS that will allow you to do this. You need to add a footer-sort of thingy in the `PageSetup` section for each page. Any scripting language should be able to help you along.

Comment: I saw a solution with Perl in http://www.osti.gov/bridge/product.biblio.jsp?query_id=0&page=0&osti_id=666084

Answer (score 1):

I tried pspdftool (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pspdftool).

I eventually got it to work, but at first I got this error:

```
pspdftool: xreftable read error
```

The source file was created with pdfjoin from pdfjam, and contained a bunch of scans from my Epson Workforce as well as generated tag pages.  I couldn't figure out a way to fix the xref table, so I converted to ps with pdf2ps and back to pdf with pdf2ps.  Then I could use this to get nice page numbers on the bottom right corner:

```
pspdftool 'number(start=1, size=20, x=550 pt, y=10 pt)' input.pdf output.pdf
```

Unfortunately, it means that any text-searchable pages are no longer searchable because the text was rasterized in the ps conversion.  Fortunately, in my case it doesn't matter.

Is there any way to fix or empty the xref table of a pdf file without losing what pages are searchable?

Comment: ``Is there any way to fix or empty the xref table of a pdf file without losing what pages are searchable?`` -> you should open a new question for this

Answer (score 1):

I took captaincomic's solution and added support for filenames containing spaces, plus giving some more informations about the progress

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo
echo This skript adds pagenumbers to a given .pdf file.
echo 
echo This skript needs the packages pdftk and enscript
echo if not installed the script will fail.
echo use the command sudo apt-get install pdftk enscript
echo to install.
echo 
input="$1"
output="${1%.pdf}-header.pdf"
echo input file is $input
echo output file will be $output
echo 
pagenum=$(pdftk "$input" dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2)
enscript -L1 --header='||Page $% of $=' --output - < <(for i in $(seq "$pagenum"); do echo; done) | ps2pdf - | pdftk "$input" multistamp - output "$output"
echo done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following `shell` script to solve this for `LaTeX` `beamer` style slides produced with `inkscape` (I `pdftk cat` the slides together into the final presentation `PDF` & then add slide numbers using the script below):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# create working directory
tmpdir=$(mktemp --directory)

# read un-numbered beamer slides PDF from STDIN & create temporary copy
cat > $tmpdir/input.pdf

# get total number of pages
pagenum=$(pdftk $tmpdir/input.pdf dump_data | awk '/NumberOfPages/{print $NF}')

# generate latex beamer document with the desired number of empty but numbered slides
printf '%s' '
\documentclass{beamer}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{forloop}
\begin{document}
 \newcounter{thepage}
  \forloop{thepage}{0}{\value{thepage} < '$pagenum'}{
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
  }
\end{document}
' > $tmpdir/numbers.tex

# compile latex file into PDF (2nd run needed for total number of pages) & redirect output to STDERR
pdflatex -output-directory=$tmpdir numbers.tex >&2 && pdflatex -output-directory=$tmpdir numbers.tex >&2

# add empty numbered PDF slides as background to (transparent background) input slides (page by
# page) & write results to STDOUT
pdftk $tmpdir/input.pdf multibackground $tmpdir/numbers.pdf output -

# remove temporary working directory with all intermediate files
rm -r $tmpdir >&2
```

The script reads `STDIN` & writes `STDOUT` printing diagnostic `pdflatex` output to `STDERR`.

So just copy-paste the above code in a text file, say `enumerate_slides.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x enumerate_slides.sh`) & call it like this:

```sh
./enumerate_slides.sh < input.pdf > output.pdf [2>/dev/null]
```

It should be easy to adjust this to any other kind of document by adjusting the `LaTeX` template to use the proper `documentclass`, paper size & style options.

***edit:***
I replaced `echo` by `$(which echo)` since in `ubuntu` symlinks `/bin/sh` to `dash` which overrides the `echo` command by a shell internal interpreting escape sequences by default & not providing the `-E` option to override this behaviour. Note that alternatively you could escape all `\` in the LaTeX template as `\\`.

***edit:***
I replaced `$(which echo)` by `printf '%s'` since in `zsh`, `which echo` returns `echo: shell built-in command` instead of `/bin/echo`.
See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/65290) for details why I decided to use `printf` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have used LibreOffice Draw for this. Adding a page number field is easy using **Insert->Field->Page Number**. And then you can copy-and-paste this field to other pages; fortunately the position is not changed and the copy-and-paste can be done quickly with **down arrow key** and **Ctrl+V**. Worked for me for a 30 page article. Maybe prone to errors for a 500+ one!

Comment: “LibreOffice Calc”? No, it’s LibreOffice Draw. I use it sometimes to add a few things to PDF files, but it often destructs a lot of things, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with **pdfcpu**:

```
pdfcpu stamp add -mode text -- "Pag. %p  " "scale:.4 abs, pos:br, rot:0  margins:10" in.pdf out.pdf
```

You can add a lot of options: look at its [website](https://pdfcpu.io/core/stamp).

---

As alternative, with GUI, there's [jPDF Tweak](https://jpdftweak.sourceforge.io/).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe pstops (part of [psutils](http://directory.fsf.org/project/psutils/)) can be used for this?

Comment: I've spent quite a bit of time on it, and it seems like psutils won't do it - unless I'm missing something.