# How to add page numbers opposite the bound edge with Postscript / Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have a 2,000+ page PDF that I need to add page numbers to. The PDF is already setup for binding. Meaning there is extra margin on right and lefthand pages to accommodate the binding.

I found the following solution from [Brian M. Hunt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608046/1815859), but it always places the page number in the same position. I know I can modify the, "sub 20 sub 20" value to change the position, but how do I make the position conditional so that righthand pages have the number near the right edge and lefthand pages have the number near the left edge?

```
gs \
  -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
  -sOutputFile=/path/to/merged.pdf \
  -c 'globaldict /MyPageCount 1 put << /EndPage {exch pop 0 eq dup {/Helvetica 12 selectfont MyPageCount =string cvs dup stringwidth pop currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get exch sub 20 sub 20 moveto show globaldict /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put } if } bind >> setpagedevice'
  -f input1.pdf -f input2.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have `MyPageCount`, so you know the page number. Using that you can determine if the page count is odd or even. Then you just select different positional logic.

Something like :

```
MyPageCount 2 mod 1 eq
{
%%insert odd numbered page positioning
}{
%%insert even numbered page positioning
} ifelse
```

[add simplified program]

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFX -sOutputFile=step_4.pdf \
  -c 'globaldict /MyPageCount 1 put
        <<
            /EndPage {
                exch pop 0 eq dup {
                    /Helvetica 12 selectfont MyPageCount 256 string cvs dup stringwidth pop currentpagedevice
                    /PageSize get 0 get exch sub
                    MyPageCount 2 mod 1 eq {
                      60
                    }
                    {
                      505
                    } ifelse
                    sub 36 moveto
                    show globaldict
                    /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put
                } if
            } bind
        >>
        setpagedevice' \
    -f "test_in.pdf"
```

Note that `=string` is unique to Ghostscript (ie won't work on any other PostScript interpreter) and pulls a pre-defined 256 character string from userdict. There are dangers to using this that I doubt you realise, because it's a subtlety of PostScript. I have instead replaced it with the portable (ie standard PostScript) construction `256 string` which has the same effect for your purposes, but creates a scratch string that can't be reused unexpectedly, unlike `=string`.

You have set `-dPDFX` (to create a PDF/X-3 compliant file) but you haven't supplied a PDF/X definition file, this means that the resulting file may not be PDF/X compliant. The process is documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/VectorDevices.htm#PDFX)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to KenS's suggestion I was able to get the page numbers added with the following script.

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFX -sOutputFile=step_4.pdf \
  -c 'globaldict /MyPageCount 1 put
        <<
            /EndPage {
                MyPageCount 2 mod 1 eq
            {
                exch pop 0 eq dup {
                    /Helvetica 12 selectfont MyPageCount =string cvs dup stringwidth pop currentpagedevice
                    /PageSize get 0 get exch sub 60 sub 36 moveto show globaldict
                    /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put
                } if
            }{
                exch pop 0 eq dup {
                    /Helvetica 12 selectfont MyPageCount =string cvs dup stringwidth pop currentpagedevice
                    /PageSize get 0 get exch sub 505 sub 36 moveto show globaldict
                    /MyPageCount MyPageCount 1 add put
                } if
            } ifelse
            } bind
        >>
        setpagedevice' \
    -f "test_in.pdf"
```

Comment: You're duplicating a whole load of PostScript in there that isn't neccesary. Its not a problem, but its inefficeint and long-winded. The only bit that needs to change is the actual media calculation. I'll put a simplified version in my answer.